# How can I propagate a rubber tree plant from a cutting?

Tags: propagation, cuttings

I wanted to propagate a cutting from my rubber tree, so I followed the instructions in the guides below:

[Garden Guides](http://www.gardenguides.com/111828-propagate-rubber-tree-plant-cutting.html)
[eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_6352277_propagate-rubber-tree-plant-cutting.html)
[Gardening Know How](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/rubber-tree/propagation-rubber-tree-plant.htm)
[Garden Web Forum](http://forums2.gardenweb.com/discussions/1485360/trimming-propagating-rubber-tree)

I trimmed a long branch off of my rubber tree, cut it diagonally about 5" from the highest bud, dusted it with rooting hormone, and set it in some potting soil. I then enclosed the pot and I have been keeping it watered and humidified with a water sprayer. Pictures are below.

It has been about 2 weeks since this procedure, and I am wondering if there is anything more that I can do to ensure this cutting thrives. The instructions say that I should pull the plant from the soil and check for new roots, but I'm afraid that doing so might hurt the plant. Also, the leaves have become floppy and are now touching the sides of my enclosure.

Should I pull up the cutting to check for new roots? What else can I do to help my cutting take root?

BTW, this question is a followup to my original question about caring for a rubber tree plant, here:
[How to trim a rubber tree plant when all of the leaves are at the top](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24117/how-to-trim-a-rubber-tree-plant-when-all-of-the-leaves-are-at-the-top)

*Click on the pictures for larger size.*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is not really anything more you can do than watch and wait.  The propagation method you chose requires patience.  One reason is due to the Ficus family having white sap which can form an impenetrable barrier to new roots forming.  Often they root from the perimeter of the cut.

- keep the humidity high
- provide bright diffuse light.  (do not let it get too hot)
- patience

Did you consider just cutting down the old plant?  Most Ficus will readily sprout new leaves from the stem where they were cut  back.

Answer (score 0):

I had success propagating my ficus cutting by first putting it just in a jar of water for several weeks, then once roots were growing I moved it to soil. I could then monitor the new root growth without shocking it too much pulling it out to check.